# Get text size using opencv python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

im trying to get the font size of text in an image, is there any library in python or can it be done using opencv? Thanks in advance

Comment: Try Tesseract -OCR to get text from image

Comment: There are many solutions for that but probably easiest way for that East Text Detector or you can use tesseract, kraken or other ocr's but I recommend East

Comment: The font size can be calculated by `cv2.threshold()` the image and then `cv2.findContours()`, and after that mean of each bounding box dimensions. But this will get you the size in pixels and not in cms or mms.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.

Comment: No representative sample image, no answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can first use a text detector or a contour detector to get the height of one line of text. That can be used to get the size of text in pixels. But after that, you need some reference to convert it to font size (which is usually defined in points). 
All of this can be done in OpenCV. If you post an image with text, some of us will be able to provide more detailed answers.

Comment: This is better suited as a comment. It is not a proper answer.

Comment: It answers what the OP has asked. I think it is not polite to deride others' answers when one does not want to help :p

Comment: In my opinion a good answer is one that shows code or at least links to documentation that shows what code is needed. A simple statement, with broad suggestions, again in my opinion, is more relevant to a comment.

Comment: In my opinion a good answer is one that answers the original question.

Comment: I do not think it is an appropriate question for this forum according to the help guides because it is asking for an recommendation. Nor is your reply adequate for an answer, since it has no real detail. It does not give him any clue how those tools get the font size. Again this is my opinion. You can disagree.